# MasterPage Inicio

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quisiera preguntar como dejar la masterpage como default en un proyecto asp.net (sitio web), la creo, pongo los menús de navegación, pero al cargarla me arroja este error

Error HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden
El servidor web está configurado para no mostrar una lista los contenidos de este directorio.

y para cargar una pagina default, tengo que poner el path en el navegador

Saludos

Comment: La pagina principal se tiene que llamar Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Las páginas maestras son simplemente para definir el aspecto, el diseño y el comportamiento estándar que desea que tengan todas las páginas.

No se trata de una página como puedan se las aspx ya que por si sola no se puede visualizar en un navegador. Lo que deberías de hacer es poner tu página Home como inicial (bien en el web.config o por la configuración de visual studio).